# Why can you bypass restricted WiFis by adding "?.jpg" to the URL?

Tags: network, wifi, access-control

I recently read an article on [Hacking a commercial airport WLAN](http://debuggable.com/posts/hacking-a-commercial-airport-wlan:480f4dd5-50a0-40c6-aa60-4afccbdd56cb). It's basically about circumventing paid airport WiFi redirections (they redirect you to a certain URL when you type something in the address bar).

You just add `?.jpg` and tada, you've done it.

My question is: **Why does this work?**

Comment: It is worth noting that this wouldn't work on all services, just particularly poorly implemented ones.

Comment: only airports? what if you leave the page by clicking a link?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Most probably the blocker is designed to let images through, maybe because they are hotlinking some images on the page where they ask for you to login.

Appending `?.jpg` to the URL makes the blocker *think* that the URL is an image. On the other hand, anything after the `?` doesn't change the actual webpage requested, it only changes the `GET` headers. (so `http://google.com/?.jpg` and `http://google.com/` give the same page).

Note that if there already is a query string in the URL (something after a question mark), then you must use `&.jpg` instead of `?.jpg`, as only the first question mark is considered for making a query string (the second question mark is considered as part of the data, generally, and this may lead to you getting the wrong page)

Basically, when you fetch a page, you can provide additional data to the server (which can then send you a custom page dependant on your data). There are two ways of doing this: a `GET` request and a `POST` request. A `GET` request puts the data in the URL itself, a `POST` request sends in in a more subtle, 'hidden' way. [Here is an example GET request on the "ask question" page of SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/ask?title=Hello%20there,%20I%20was%20created%20by%20a%20GET%20request). A note: it is not necessary that there is data when you use a `GET` request. When you fetch a normal webpage, that is also a `GET` request, without data.